# Actionscript-3 - How to fix display frame rate to 60?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, frame-rate

There are **2 different** FPS:

- background FPS for sprite update

  - goes as fast as CPU allows
  - more or less constant 60 FPS (cheap sprite update)
- display FPS (visible with Fraps)

  - goes up to 60 when sprites move wild around
  - **drops to 0 when no sprite moves**

I want to make the display FPS stay at 60 FPS. If Adobe made it impossible to change that I need to know or ...

**How do I make the display FPS stay at 60 ?**

***To clear misunderstandings:*** Fraps hooks the WinApi function [`SwapBuffers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So every time a game window displays a new rendered scene by swapping buffers, Fraps has the chance to copy buffer content and put some FPS counter on it. Flash is optimized to save GPU time. When nothing changes nothing is drawn to the other buffer and no buffer swapping is performed. Actually this is a good thing. But I still want to know if I can disable this optimization. I'm not trying to disable vsync but to equal the GPU FPS with the CPU FPS.

---

This is how I update:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public function Main()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void
    {
        //updateSprites();
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(frameRate="60",backgroundColor="0xffffff",width="960",height="540")]
public class SimpleSprite extends MovieClip
{
    public function SimpleSprite()
    {
        for (var i: int = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            var angle: Number = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
            var color: uint = 0x1000000 * Math.random();
            var length: Number = 1024;

            graphics.lineStyle(2, color);
            graphics.moveTo(-Math.sin(angle) * length, -Math.cos(angle) * length);
            graphics.lineTo(Math.sin(angle) * length, Math.cos(angle) * length);
        }

        x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(event: Event): void
    {
        rotation += 0.002;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to periodically check how many milliseconds have gone by and stop doing any processing until the next frame. Google "elastic racetrack" and "greenthreading".

Comment: @AmyBlankenship This doesn't help me. My code performance is enough to keep up with 60 FPS but Flash drops it to 0 anyways.

Comment: Clearly there's something you're doing that is impacting performance, whether it's instantiating/redrawing too many objects or whatever. You'll need to provide more specifics to get other suggestions.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Maybe I expressed myself unclearly. It's Flash's optimization. When there is no movement on the stage because it is empty for example the FPS drops to 0. I move 1 sprite too slow and it also drops to a low value.

Answer (score 1):

I found an *unsatisfying* way to accomplish what I asked for:

Add a sprite to the stage that is **invisible by alpha** and let it move on the screen. If it leaves the screen the frame rate will drop again.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an ENTERFRAME event listener, it **will** fire with each frame (up to requested FPS rate), regardless if there's any redrawing going on or not. If it drops below that, then it just means it didn't manage to render frames that fast. A wild guess? I'd say it's code performance. :-)

Also, Timer documentation states that you shouldn't use it for intervals shorter than 20ms, and setting it lower than 16.6ms will mess with flash inner workings.

[Timer Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer%28%29)

I would suggest refactoring your app to use ENTERFRAME events instead of Timer events, and using actual elapsed time between frames to calculate animation positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Adobe Scout. I it will show you when flash frames are running and when the display is updated. You can get a lot more detail on how your application is working. Why do you want Flash to update the physical display when nothing has changed? It won't accomplish anything. If you really want to force this, modify some bits on the display and set them back again. Scout will show exactly which bits are updated in each frame.

Comment: One of the problems is that Flash doesn't update the display when you make tiny changes. Try a project with high resolution and rotate a big texture **slowly**! You will see the texture jump from one degree to another.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do not use timers. It's not meant to do what you're trying to get it to.
2. Set your SWF framerate to 60 during compilation, either on the SWF header meta tags or your compiler settings.
3. Use an `ENTER_FRAME` event to run your code (e.g. `updateSprites()`).

You may skip some frames depending on how complex the animation is. **That is inevitable**. Trying to "force" the framerate won't work and will only make things worse. If you need something to run 60 times a second you can check `getTimer()` inside your `ENTER_FRAME` event and make sure something is being done that number of times. But it'll still be rendered at a lower framerate.

Comment: No. It's just the same. Review the question please!

Comment: I think you have a serious problem with your question. There's no such thing as a secondary display FPS. How are you measuring it to say it "dropped" to 0 fps?

Comment: I think you have a serious problem with your understanding of Flash. Try Fraps then you'll see.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Well, here is the issue: Fraps *doesn't know* Flash's framerate, it just knows the rate of the updates it *sees*. Flash could be updating the screen at 1000fps, but because it is the same content (like you said), there's no way for Fraps to count it. I still think you have a serious problem with your question, starting with the fact that you're not actually measuring what you think you are measuring.

Comment: n4pgamer, next time you're asking a question on StackOverflow, make sure you are ready to be helped and is willing to accept you may not be entirely sure what you're doing. That way you'll learn something and might solve your problem. As a bonus, not being hostile towards people who actually know what they're talking about and are trying to help you will make you a better person. This was not that time. Good luck.